# How can I make my laptop a server for the Intranet?

Tags: 12.04, intranet

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and I have to organize an intranet competition for which I want my laptop to act as sever so that others can see the questions and submit their answers directly on to my server.

I have already installed Lamp and separately installed mysql, apache, php5 etc and by using a single command `apt-get install lamp-server^` but I don't know how to make an intranet server.

Please someone help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give to this laptop a static ip.

Lets say that your router gateway is 192.168.1.254 and your primary network is eth0

**Edit the /etc/network/interfaces**

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

to look like this

> auto lo eth0
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> iface eth0 inet static
>
> address **192.168.1.10**
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> broadcast 192.168.1.255
>
> network 192.168.1.0
>
> gateway 192.168.1.254
>
> dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254

**save, exit and restart networking (or reboot)**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Now from any intranet pc browser write:

```
http://192.168.1.10
```

you must see (as you say having install the lamp server) the Apache message **It Works!**

Now you can install any Lamp application in subdirectories, which can be called from any intranet pc like this:

> `http://192.168.1.10/your_app`